# Visual Studio 2008 automatically add namespaces like Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, import, using-statement

Does VS2008 have a feature akin to Eclipse's ability to automatically add import declarations for undefined namespaces?

Comment: Nope.  I'm hoping that add this to future releases because it would be incredibly helpful and cut down on HOURS of work.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a refrence to the assembly that contains the namespace just go over(or select) the type you want add its namespace then CTRL + . and it will add the namespace

this is what it looks like :

[alt text http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/6976/91301094.png](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/6976/91301094.png)

Answer (score 0):

VS will help you resolve references to types defined in namespaces that you haven't included. Right-click on a class name, select "resolve", and pick an option.

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned there is no way like in Eclipse, unfortunately. Additional plugins however, like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html) or [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/) support you further in these tasks.